# Does LibGit2Sharp support initialize shared repository?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp, bonobo

i want to use Bonobo git server and want to initialize --shared --bare repositories.

i check the source code of `bonobo git server` and by default it creates bare repositories. i need to include `--shared` as well, but there is no function in `LibGit2Sharp.init(path, bare)` with shared option. i check the LibGit2Sharp source in git hub also.

is by default LibGit2Sharp.init creates shared repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is by default LibGit2Sharp.init creates shared repository?

Similarly to **[git init](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init)**, by default LibGit2Sharp will use permissions reported by umask(2). (ie. `--shared=umask)`

What you're requesting (eg. `--shared`, `--shared=group` or `--shared=all`) isn't supported by LibGit2Sharp as of now. However, it looks like it's already **[exposed](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/repository.h#L213-L229)** by the underlying `libgit2` library.

The best course of action regarding your question would to to log a feature request in the LibGit2Sharp **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues)**.

Considering this only requires to leverage some existing features of the underlying native library, the development of this feature shouldn't be very complex to perform.

Comment: i didn't understand ```by default LibGit2Sharp will use permissions reported by umask(2)```  what is umask(2)

Comment: See the link in the answer pointing to the `git init` documentation. More info about `umask(2)` can be found in the linux man pages (cf. https://www.google.com/search?q=umask(2))

Comment: i filed a feature request :-) [link](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1151)